# jquery draggable: how to limit the draggable area?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a draggable object (div), and some droppable ones (table TD's). I want the user to drag my draggable object to one of those droppable TD's.

I enable draggable and droppable this way:

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
$(".droppable").droppable();
```

The problem is that with this the user can drag the div anywhere on the screen, including out of the droppable area.

How can I limit the boundary area for the draggable object?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use the "containment" option:

[jQuery UI API - Draggable Widget - containment](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)

The documentation says it only accepts the values: `'parent'`, `'document'`, `'window'`, `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` but I seem to remember it will accept a selector such as '#container' too.

Comment: I did thums up friend. You saved me a lot ;) Just solved by reading first line and it's recommended value in your answer.

Comment: its not accepting the Selectors though. Even if I enter a selector it is dragging beyond that selector. Any other way to do this? Anyways Thumbs up!

Comment: @Mattyod how to do this without a containment?

Comment: When I used containment, it doesn't let the draggable item go all the way to the edge of the object

Answer (score 19):

```
$(function() { $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "window" }); });
```

of this code does not display.
Full code and Demo:
http://www.limitsizbilgi.com/div-tasima-surukle-birak-div-drag-and-drop-jquery.html

In order to limit the element inside its parent:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "window" });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a code example to follow. #thumbnail is a DIV parent of the #handle DIV

```
buildDraggable = function() {
    $( "#handle" ).draggable({
    containment: '#thumbnail',
    drag: function(event) {
        var top = $(this).position().top;
        var left = $(this).position().left;

        ICZoom.panImage(top, left);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See excerpt from official documentation for [`containment` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment):

> ### containment
>
> **Default:** `false`
>
> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified
>   element or region.
>   **Multiple types supported:**
>
> - **Selector**: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.
> - **Element**: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
> - **String**: Possible values: `"parent"`, `"document"`, `"window"`.
> - **Array**: An array defining a bounding box in the form `[ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]`.
>
> **Code examples:**
>   Initialize the draggable with the `containment` option specified:
>
> ```javascript
> $( ".selector" ).draggable({
>     containment: "parent" 
> });
> ```
>
> Get or set the `containment` option, after initialization:
>
> ```javascript
> // Getter
> var containment = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "containment" );
> // Setter
> $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "containment", "parent" );
> ```

Comment: what about specific element ? , i don't want to add "parent", "document", "window"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $( ".droppable-area" ).sortable({
                connectWith: ".connected-sortable",
                containment: ".droppable-area", //(parent div)
                stack: '.connected-sortable div'
            }).disableSelection();
});
```