# make draggable elements stop on div-border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

In my body I have a few images in a `wrapper` div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="1.png" id="img1" />
    <img src="2.png" id="img2" />
    <img src="3.png" id="img3" />
</div>
```

which are all draggable with jQueryUI:

```
var $images = $('#img1, #img2, #img3')
    $images.draggable({ start: dragStart,
                        cursor: 'move',
                        stop: dragEnd });
```

All elements are `position: absolute;` and the wrapper has a fixed `width: 1000px; height: 800px`
What I would like to know is if its possible to stop the dragging when the `img` collides with the end of div and  fire an event if it collides.

Comment: Have you tried `containment` option http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237161/jquery-draggable-how-to-limit-the-draggable-area

Comment: but how can i fire an event when drag against the end?