# Restrict dragging within a specific DIV only

Tags: javascript, jquery

See JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/2/

1. How do I restrict the dragging only within `#OuterWrapper` ?
2. Why can't I get a newline in the textarea by hitting ENTER?

   var x = 0, y = 0;

   interact('#outWrap_1')
       .draggable({
           onmove: function (event) {
               x += event.dx;
               y += event.dy;

   ```
           event.target.style.webkitTransform =
           event.target.style.transform =
               'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
       }
   })
   .inertia(true)
   .restrict({
       drag: "#OuterWrapper", // how to restrict dragging to this DIV only
       endOnly: true
   });
   ```

Comment: drag: document.getElementById('OuterWrapper'), endOnly: false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use containment

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

check this
[jquery draggable: how to limit the draggable area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237161/jquery-draggable-how-to-limit-the-draggable-area)